# Autocomplete - Append and getting only the text the user has inputed on combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete

I have a `ComboBox` that I set up like this:

```
this.cmbCustomerJob.DisplayMember = "display";
this.cmbCustomerJob.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
this.cmbCustomerJob.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
this.cmbCustomerJob.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
```

However I'm messing with the `KeyPressed` event to prevent the user from entering a new term into the `ComboBox`, however when I do `cmbCustomerJob.Text` it returns even the suggested portion, how can I get only what the user has typed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I did this:

```
strNew = ((ComboBox)sender).Text.Substring(0, ((ComboBox)sender).SelectionStart) + c.ToString();
```

It grabs the `Text` from the start (`0`) to were the selection begins (`SelectionStart`), the `c.ToString()` is the `KeyPressEventArgs.KeyChar`